# Creating composite raster from rasters with different spatial extent without losing information using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, mosaic, average

I am creating a composite raster using several individual rasters with different spatial extents (captured from different times), see image below.

[image: "Target area is shown in light blue and the individual rasters are shown in light green"]

The idea here is that I want to create one mosaic composite raster without losing any information (i.e. calculating means of repeating raster values) in order to have a more complete picture. I would normally use the [Mosaic to New Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) tool for a situation like this, however, in this particular case there is quite a bit of overlap between the rasters so I just want to make sure I don't lose any data.

Comment: Impossible without losing Informationen. You have to resample or clip to one target Raster.

Comment: @user2856 Oh I see it now, that works thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mosaic to New Raster tool with the mosaic method set to "MEAN"

[image]